# How to render database row as html header in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am doing web application where i have one table. i am making row data as html table header based on id.
This is what i tried. This is controller code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

    var table = new List<test> {
        new test { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "12345678", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new test { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "1/1/2015", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },


        new test { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "123", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },
        new test { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "1/1/20244", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" }

    };

    var items = table.Where(x => x.Emp_id == 1 || x.Emp_id == 2).ToList();
    var headers = items.Select(x => x.Label).Distinct().ToList();
    var employers = items.Select(x => x.Emp_id).Distinct().ToList();

    if(employers.Count > 1)
        headers.Insert(0, "Name");

    var data = new List<List<string>>();
    data.Add(headers);            

    foreach (var emp in employers)
    {
        var row = new List<string>();
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {                    
            if (header != "Name")
            {
                var cell = items.Where(x => x.Label == header && x.Emp_id == emp).FirstOrDefault();
                row.Add(cell == null ? "" : cell.Value);
            }                        
            else
                row.Add(items.Where(x => x.Emp_id == emp).First().Name);
        }
        data.Add(row);
    }

    return View(data);
}
```

This is view code

```
@model List<List<string>>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var header in Model.First())
            {
                <th>@header</th>
            }
        </tr>        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in Model.Skip(1))
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    <td>@cell</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now i am able to render as below.

```
Name    DocumentNumber  ExpiryDate
First   12345678        1/1/2015
Second  123             1/1/20244
```

But i want header to be appeared for each row of data. For example if i add one more header Issueddate for Emp_id 2(i hardcoded at the begining) the output should look like below.

```
 Name   DocumentNumber  ExpiryDate
 First  12345678        1/1/2015
 Name   DocumentNumber  ExpiryDate Issueddate
 Second  123            1/1/20244  1/1/2015
```

So in the above code where i should make changes to appear headers for each row of data? Hope you clearly understood the scenario. Thanks in advance. i tried as you said but header appends to each row of data as below.

```
 Name   DocumentNumber  ExpiryDate Issueddate
 First  12345678        1/1/2015
 Name   DocumentNumber  ExpiryDate Issueddate
 Second  123            1/1/20244  1/1/2015
```

now issued date should come for only emp_id with 2? Hope you understood.

This is my code.

```
var table = new List<test> {
        new test { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "12345678", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new test { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "1/1/2015", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },


        new test { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "123", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },
        new test { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "1/1/20244", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },
           new test { Label = "Issuedon", Value = "1/1/20244", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" }
```

With respect to above data i want output like this below.

```
Name   DocumentNumber  ExpiryDate
 First  12345678        1/1/2015
 Name   DocumentNumber  ExpiryDate Issueddon
 Second  123            1/1/20244  1/1/20244
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the first `loop` to inside the second `loop`

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        @for (int i = 1; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {

              foreach (var header in Model.First())
              {
                  if (header == "Issuedon")
                  {
                      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[i][3])) //assuming issue date will be at 3rd index , thoug this approch is not good as OP send model as List of string not model which is a ideal option
                      {
                       <th>@header
                      </th>
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          continue;
                      }
                  }

                   else
                  {
                    <th>@header
                      </th>
                  }    
              }

            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in Model[i])
                {
                    <td>@cell
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>


        }
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**SIDE NOTE** : assuming issue date will be at 3rd index , though this approach is not good But there is no other option as OP send model as List of string not model which should be an ideal option

Comment: i tried as you said. but header appears for each row. But header issueddate should appear for empid 2 only. i showd output above

Comment: Can you please post the code how you are adding `issuedate` to `model` in `c#`

Comment: Yes this will work but somewhat i feel like i am hardcoding. If i have more headers for different id's then this approach will not work. So is anyway to overcome from this?

Comment: @Niranjan The approach should be we will pass a class as `Model`, that class will contain `list of objects contains header values` and as well as `list of objects containing values(rows) and each property of the object should know what's the corresponding header value`. So based on this if value is present we will show hide the header labels